# How to set up Nginx to serve image files without extension

Tags: nginx, web

I am trying to develop a very simple image server with nginx but I haven't been able to set up the right configuration yet.

The idea is that I am saving images without the file extension (i.e. that a file named *"image1.png"* is saved as *"image1"*)

Moreover I would like nginx to render the image on the web browser when I type the url **mypath/image1**

I want a solution that allows me to serve different file extensions like **.gif** **.jpg** **.jpeg** **.png** etc without downloading the image

So is it possible to set up an Nginx config to do what I want?

Answer (score 1):

You Can Try This. Nginx try_files with default type as jpg or png. Nginx will look for the $url and if not found will add the .jpg at the end from that path.

```
server{
        location /images {

            root /var/www/pathtomyimages;

            default_type "text/jpg";
            try_files  $uri $uri.jpg;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The problem is I have files with different extensions, like .gif .png .jpeg .jpg

So I would like to know how to resolve the mime.type of the file without having to use the extension

Comment: I apologize. I understand your questions a bit more now.

Comment: It's ok!! I edited my question after your answer. This issue is something I am trying to set up and I haven't find a way to do it so far

Answer (score 0):

```
server{
        location /images {
            root /var/www/pathtomyimages;
            default_type image/webp;
        }
    }
```

Setting this config made it possible